# loading QICon asynchronously in QListview

Tags: qt, qt4, nokia

I am using a delegate to show a standard item model data into a listview in qt.
The model has a QIcon and a header and subheader strings.

Now i want to load remote images via http into the listview asynchronously. 
How can i do this?

I have already got the listview running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to solve your task, and correct answer depends on how you're building your ui and what it's meant for and how other components in your application work. Nevertheless, here's an idea for you to consider:

1. Create a model for your listview, a guess each item of your model should have a link to the icon\image which you're going to download.
2. Use [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) to connect to **asynchronously** download the image via http. Example of you can do this is here: [qt networkManager get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233057/qt-networkmanager-get/5284384#5284384)
3. Once an image is downloaded network manager's "[finished](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished)" signal handler will be called, there you need to update a record in your model corresponding to the downloaded link with the pointer to the image object.
4. For the list you can use an [item delegate](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstyleditemdelegate.html) to draw an empty place holder (or just a default image) for the records which don't have an icon downloaded yet;
5. Make sure you're synchronizing your model ([QMutex](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmutex.html) [QSemaphore](http://doc.trolltech.com/main-snapshot/qsemaphore.html) [QWaitCondition](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwaitcondition.html))

hope this helps, regards

Comment: i thought there would be some kind of ready made functionality for this. Yeah i did this, and it works now.. :)